# Database: Should ids be sequential?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to use an id as a primary key for my table. In each record, I am also storing an id from an other source, but these ids are in no way sequential.

Should I add an (auto-incremented) column with a "new" id? It is very important that queries by the id are as fast as possible.

Some info:

- The content of my table is only stored "temporary", The table gets often cleared (TRUNCATE) and than filled with new content.
- It's a sql-server 2008
- After writing content to the table, I create an index for the id column

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you are sure the supplied id's are unique, there's no need to create another (surrogate) id to use as primary key.

Comment: If you are sure data is unique then I will make that column PK, to make sure  db wont collapse in the future is data provider make a change on that data.

Comment: Great, thanks! The data provider is OSM, I think their ids will stay ids ;)

Answer (score 2):

Under most circumstances, an index on the existing id should be sufficient.  You can make it slightly faster by declaring it as a primary key.

From what you describe a new id is not necessary for performance.  If you do add one, the table will be slightly larger, which has a (very small) negative effect on performance.

If the existing `id` is not numeric (or not an integer), then there might be a small gain from using a more efficient type for the index.  But, your best bet is to make the existing `id` a primary key (although this might affect load performance).

Note:  I usually prefer synthetic primary keys, so this answer is very specific to your question.

Comment: Thanks! The ids are all 32bit integers, just very large.

Answer (score -2):

If you are after speed I would join the two IDs together (either from the application or stored proc) and then put them in one column

Comment: This would greatly increase the risk of collisions. Not a good approach for this in my opinion.

Comment: If you know the maximum number of IDs from the other set then you just need to make sure you start counting from a higher number? e.g. the highest ID you want to store is 98765, so you just start at 100000+ID